# actulizacion de registros en la base de datos PHP

Tags: php

este un parte del codigo para actualizar registros pero me sale este eroro:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   mysql_fetch_array() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Aeroasistencia\aplicacionTruji\modificarProceso.php:17
>   Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Aeroasistencia\aplicacionTruji\modificarProceso.php on
>   line 17

no se como solucionarlo

obiamente ya tengo el formulario pero no me actualiza.

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Datos a actualizar.</title>
<META name='robot' content='noindex, nofollow'>
</head>

<?php 
$id = $_POST['id'];

$conexion =  mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","admin123","database");


    $query = "SELECT FROM usuario WHERE id = '".$id."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conexion,$query);

while ($registro = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

echo "
<body>

<div align='center'>
    <table border='0' width='600' style='font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt' id='table1'>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2'><h3 align='center'>Actualice los datos que considere</h3></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2'>En los campos del formulario puede ver los valores actuales, 
            si no se cambian los valores se mantienen iguales.</td>
        </tr>
        <form method='POST' action='actualiza.php'>
        <tr>
            <td width='50%'>&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='50%'>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='50%'><p align='center'><b>Cedula: </b></td>
            <td width='50%'><p align='center'><input type='text' name='id_funcinario' size='20' value='".$registro['id_Funcionario']."'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='50%'><p align='center'><b>Primer Nombre :</b></td>
            <td width='50%'><p align='center'><input type='text' name='primer_Nombre' size='20' value='".$registro['primer_Nombre']."'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='50%'><p align='center'><b>Segundo Nombre :</b></td>
            <td width='50%'><p align='center'><input type='text' name='segundo_Nombre' size='20' value='".$registro['segundo_Nombre']."'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='50%'><p align='center'><b>Primer Apellido :</b></td>
            <td width='50%'><p align='center'><input type='text' name='primer_Apellido' size='20' value='".$registro['primer_Apellido']."'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='50%'><p align='center'><b>Segundo Apellido :</b></td>
            <td width='50%'><p align='center'><input type='text' name='segundo_Apellido' size='20' value='".$registro['segundo_Apellido']."'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='50%'><p align='center'><b>Cargo Funcionario :</b></td>
            <td width='50%'><p align='center'><input type='text' name='cargo_Funcionario' size='20' value='".$registro['cargo_Funcionario']."'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='50%'><p align='center'><b>Telefono Funcionario :</b></td>
            <td width='50%'><p align='center'><input type='text' name='telefono_Funcionario' size='20' value='".$registro['telefono_Funcionario']."'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='50%'><p align='center'><b>Edad Funcionario :</b></td>
            <td width='50%'><p align='center'><input type='text' name='edad_Funcionario' size='20' value='".$registro['edad_Funcionario']."'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='50%'><p align='center'><b>Sexo Funcionario :</b></td>
            <td width='50%'><p align='center'><input type='text' name='sexo_Funcionario' size='20' value='".$registro['sexo_Funcionario']."'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='50%'>&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='50%'>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <input type='hidden' name='id' value='$id'>
        <tr>
            <td width='100%' colspan='2'>
            <p align='center'>
            <input type='submit' value='Actualizar datos' name='B1'></td>
        </tr>
        </form>
    </table>
</div>
";
} 
?>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ahora sale este error:
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Aeroasistencia\aplicacionTruji\modificarProceso.php on line 17

Comment: Sugiero que hagas [una edición de tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/146633/edit), poniendo al final de ella como tienes el código ahora. Para fines de documentación y para no desautorizar las demás respuestas, no cambies el código posteado al principio, pon el nuevo código aparte para revisarlo.

Comment: El error que recibes es porque la consulta tiene un error tipográfico (debe ser `SELECT * FROM...` en lugar de `SELECT FROM...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu código no tiene solamente un **error de sintaxis** al mezclar funciones `mysql*` con funciones `mysqli`, sino que persiste en él **un grave agujero de seguridad**, el cual conviene corregir.

De hecho, si tu pasas la consulta así:

```
$query = "SELECT FROM usuario WHERE id = '".$id."'";
```

Cualquier usuario mal intencionado podría inyectarte código dañino no sólo en la base de datos, sino en tu sistema completo.

Este fallo se corrige de una forma muy simple, mediante el uso de consultas preparadas.

También he aprovechado para corregir algunas cosas. Por ejemplo, tú imprimes una etiqueta `<body>` cada vez dentro del `while`, por lo que tendrás un HTML con un montón de `body`, lo cual es incorrecto.

Yo ha aplicado ciertos criterios de optimización en el código, como por ejemplo poner en el `SELECT` solamente aquellas columnas que se van a usar. A veces uno usa `SELECT *` por comodidad, pero esto es una mala práctica, ya que quizá estamos trayendo columnas que no vamos a usar nunca.

Por otra parte, `mysqli` tiene un problema que para mí es demasiado incómodo y es que hace dar demasiadas vueltas para obtener los resultados cuando se usan consultas preparadas. Los valores se podrían obtener en un array asociativo como los tenías con `get_result`, pero resulta que esa función no está presente en todas las instalaciones de PHP porque es un driver aparte. No entiendo por qué los diseñadores de `mysqli` hicieron eso así. Lo cierto es que aquí el código es un poco más *verbose* por eso, porque hay que vincular cada columna explícitamente a una variable, **que será la que usarás más adelante en la impresión de la tabla**. Toma nota de ello, porque en la tabla deberás imprimir los valores así por ejemplo: `value='".$primerNombre."'` y no como lo tenías antes: <s>`$registro['primer_Nombre']`</s>.

Te dejo aquí el código modificado. Espero te sea de utilidad. Ten en cuenta que aquí estamos corrigiendo varias cosas, y la más importante de ella es que **estamos escribiendo un código que es seguro contra posibles ataques que podrían ser bastante graves**.

```
echo "<body>";
$id = $_POST['id'];

$conexion =  mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","admin123","database");

$query = "  SELECT
                    id_Funcionario,
                    primer_Nombre,
                    segundo_Nombre,
                    primer_Apellido,
                    segundo_Apellido,
                    cargo_Funcionario,
                    telefono_Funcionario,
                    edad_Funcionario,
                    sexo_Funcionario
            FROM usuario
            WHERE id = ?";

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conexion, $query)) {

    /* ligar parámetros para marcadores */
    /*IMPORTANTE: Si id no es numérico en la base de datos, cambia la i por una s*/
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $id);

    /* ejecutar la consulta */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    $stmt->store_result();

    /* Bind resultados a variables */
    $stmt->bind_result($idFuncionario, $primerNombre, $segundoNombre, $primerApellido, $segundoApellido, $cargo, $tel, $edad, $sexo);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo "

    <div align='center'>
        <table border='0' width='600' style='font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt' id='table1'>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='2'><h3 align='center'>Actualice los datos que considere</h3></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='2'>En los campos del formulario puede ver los valores actuales,
                si no se cambian los valores se mantienen iguales.</td>
            </tr>
            <form method='POST' action='actualiza.php'>
            <tr>
                <td width='50%'>&nbsp;</td>
                <td width='50%'>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><b>Cedula: </b></td>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><input type='text' name='id_funcinario' size='20' value='".$idFuncionario."'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><b>Primer Nombre :</b></td>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><input type='text' name='primer_Nombre' size='20' value='".$primerNombre."'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><b>Segundo Nombre :</b></td>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><input type='text' name='segundo_Nombre' size='20' value='".$segundoNombre."'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><b>Primer Apellido :</b></td>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><input type='text' name='primer_Apellido' size='20' value='".$primerApellido."'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><b>Segundo Apellido :</b></td>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><input type='text' name='segundo_Apellido' size='20' value='".$segundoApellido."'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><b>Cargo Funcionario :</b></td>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><input type='text' name='cargo_Funcionario' size='20' value='".$cargo."'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><b>Telefono Funcionario :</b></td>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><input type='text' name='telefono_Funcionario' size='20' value='".$tel."'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><b>Edad Funcionario :</b></td>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><input type='text' name='edad_Funcionario' size='20' value='".$edad."'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><b>Sexo Funcionario :</b></td>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><input type='text' name='sexo_Funcionario' size='20' value='".$sexo."'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width='50%'>&nbsp;</td>
                <td width='50%'>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <input type='hidden' name='id' value='$id'>
            <tr>
                <td width='100%' colspan='2'>
                <p align='center'>
                <input type='submit' value='Actualizar datos' name='B1'></td>
            </tr>
            </form>
        </table>
    </div>
    ";
    } 

}else{
    echo "Hubo un error en la consulta";
}
?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo por el conocimiento

Comment: @CristianAntonioTrujilloGris Me alegro de que la respuesta te haya ayudado a resolver el problema. Por favor, cuando sea posible l◔_◔: **[¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)** en el Centro de Ayuda.

Comment: pero no me esta actualizando los datos

Comment: ¿Actualizando los datos? Tu consulta es un `SELECT`, es para traer datos y mostrarlos en una tabla, según lo que tienes en tu código. ¿A qué te refieres con que no está actualizando?

Comment: igual no me trae la consulta

Comment: tocaria que vieras el codigo completo

Answer (score 1):

Los errores que puedo ver son:

1. Te hacia falta el `*` que indica la selección de todos los datos de tu tabla.
2. Al tratar de utilizar funciones MySQL ya obsoletas

Tu codigo debe de quedar asi:

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Datos a actualizar.</title>
<META name='robot' content='noindex, nofollow'>
</head>

<?php 
$id = $_POST['id'];

$conexion =  mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","admin123","database");


    $query = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE id = '".$id."'";
    $result = $conexion->query($query);


while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

echo "
<body>

<div align='center'>
    <table border='0' width='600' style='font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt' id='table1'>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2'><h3 align='center'>Actualice los datos que considere</h3></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2'>En los campos del formulario puede ver los valores actuales, 
            si no se cambian los valores se mantienen iguales.</td>
        </tr>
        <form method='POST' action='actualiza.php'>
        <tr>
            <td width='50%'>&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='50%'>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='50%'><p align='center'><b>Cedula: </b></td>
            <td width='50%'><p align='center'><input type='text' name='id_funcinario' size='20' value='".$registro['id_Funcionario']."'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='50%'><p align='center'><b>Primer Nombre :</b></td>
            <td width='50%'><p align='center'><input type='text' name='primer_Nombre' size='20' value='".$registro['primer_Nombre']."'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='50%'><p align='center'><b>Segundo Nombre :</b></td>
            <td width='50%'><p align='center'><input type='text' name='segundo_Nombre' size='20' value='".$registro['segundo_Nombre']."'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='50%'><p align='center'><b>Primer Apellido :</b></td>
            <td width='50%'><p align='center'><input type='text' name='primer_Apellido' size='20' value='".$registro['primer_Apellido']."'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='50%'><p align='center'><b>Segundo Apellido :</b></td>
            <td width='50%'><p align='center'><input type='text' name='segundo_Apellido' size='20' value='".$registro['segundo_Apellido']."'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='50%'><p align='center'><b>Cargo Funcionario :</b></td>
            <td width='50%'><p align='center'><input type='text' name='cargo_Funcionario' size='20' value='".$registro['cargo_Funcionario']."'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='50%'><p align='center'><b>Telefono Funcionario :</b></td>
            <td width='50%'><p align='center'><input type='text' name='telefono_Funcionario' size='20' value='".$registro['telefono_Funcionario']."'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='50%'><p align='center'><b>Edad Funcionario :</b></td>
            <td width='50%'><p align='center'><input type='text' name='edad_Funcionario' size='20' value='".$registro['edad_Funcionario']."'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='50%'><p align='center'><b>Sexo Funcionario :</b></td>
            <td width='50%'><p align='center'><input type='text' name='sexo_Funcionario' size='20' value='".$registro['sexo_Funcionario']."'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width='50%'>&nbsp;</td>
            <td width='50%'>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <input type='hidden' name='id' value='$id'>
        <tr>
            <td width='100%' colspan='2'>
            <p align='center'>
            <input type='submit' value='Actualizar datos' name='B1'></td>
        </tr>
        </form>
    </table>
</div>
";
} 
?>
</body>

</html>
```

**Nota:** **mysql_fetch_array**

> Esta extensión fue declarada obsoleta en PHP 5.5.0 y eliminada en PHP
>   7.0.0. En su lugar debería utilzarse las extensiones MySQLi o PDO_MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Tenés mal escrita la query:

```
$query = "SELECT FROM usuario WHERE id = '".$id."'";
```

Y al estar mal, entonces tira un error y por eso no podés utilizar la función `mysql_fetch_array()`. Lo correcto sería:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE id = '".$id."'";
```

También podes seleccionar los campos de la tabla que querés mostrar.

Comment: listo pero sigue el mismo error:   Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Aeroasistencia\aplicacionTruji\modificarProceso.php on line                                                               
$query = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE id = '".$id."'";
$result = mysqli_query($conexion,$query);

while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){