# Realizar update de los registros en Php

Tags: php

Iniciar actualización.

```
<div align="center">
    <table border="0" width="600" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt" id="table1">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><h3 align="center">Actualizacion de datos</h3></td>
        </tr>
        <form method="POST" action="modificarProceso.php">
            <tr>
                <td width="50%">&nbsp;</td>
                <td width="50%">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="50%">
                    <p align="center"><b>ID del funcionario a actualizar: </b></td>
                        <td width="50%">
                            <p align="center"><input type="text" name="id" size="20"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="50%">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td width="50%">&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="100%" colspan="2">
                                    <p align="center">
                                        <input type="submit" value="Iniciar actualización" name="btn-actulizar"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </form>
                            </table>
                            <input type="button" value="Volver de donde viniste!" onclick="history.back(-1)" />
                        </div>

                    </body>

                    </html>
```

**modificarProceso.php**

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Datos a actualizar.</title>
    <META name='robot' content='noindex, nofollow'>
</head>

<?php 
echo "<body>";
$id = $_POST['id'];

$conexion =  mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","admin123","database");

$query = "  SELECT
                    id_Funcionario,
                    primer_Nombre,
                    segundo_Nombre,
                    primer_Apellido,
                    segundo_Apellido,
                    cargo_Funcionario,
                    telefono_Funcionario,
                    edad_Funcionario,
                    sexo_Funcionario
            FROM usuario
            WHERE id = ?";

/*Prepara la setencia SQl para su ejecucion*/
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conexion, $query)) {

    /*Agrega variables a una sentencia preparada como parametros*/
    /* ligar parámetros para marcadores */
    /*IMPORTANTE: Si id no es numérico en la base de datos, cambia la i por una s*/
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $id);

    /* Ejecuta una consulta preparada */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /*Se transfiere los  resultados de la ultima consulta*/
    $stmt->store_result();

    /* Vincula las variables a una setencia preparada para el almacenamineto de resultados */
    $stmt->bind_result($idFuncionario, $primerNombre, $segundoNombre, $primerApellido, $segundoApellido, $cargo, $tel, $edad, $sexo);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo "

    <div align='center'>
        <table border='0' width='600' style='font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt' id='table1'>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='2'><h3 align='center'>Actualice los datos que considere</h3></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='2'>En los campos del formulario puede ver los valores actuales,
                si no se cambian los valores se mantienen iguales.</td>
            </tr>
            <form method='POST' action='actualiza.php'>
            <tr>
                <td width='50%'>&nbsp;</td>
                <td width='50%'>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><b>Cedula: </b></td>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><input type='text' name='id_funcinario' size='20' value='".$idFuncionario."'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><b>Primer Nombre :</b></td>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><input type='text' name='primer_Nombre' size='20' value='".$primerNombre."'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><b>Segundo Nombre :</b></td>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><input type='text' name='segundo_Nombre' size='20' value='".$segundoNombre."'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><b>Primer Apellido :</b></td>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><input type='text' name='primer_Apellido' size='20' value='".$primerApellido."'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><b>Segundo Apellido :</b></td>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><input type='text' name='segundo_Apellido' size='20' value='".$segundoApellido."'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><b>Cargo Funcionario :</b></td>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><input type='text' name='cargo_Funcionario' size='20' value='".$cargo."'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><b>Telefono Funcionario :</b></td>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><input type='text' name='telefono_Funcionario' size='20' value='".$tel."'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><b>Edad Funcionario :</b></td>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><input type='text' name='edad_Funcionario' size='20' value='".$edad."'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><b>Sexo Funcionario :</b></td>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><input type='text' name='sexo_Funcionario' size='20' value='".$sexo."'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width='50%'>&nbsp;</td>
                <td width='50%'>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <input type='hidden' name='id' value='$id'>
            <tr>
                <td width='100%' colspan='2'>
                <p align='center'>
                <input type='submit' value='Actualizar datos' name='B1'></td>
            </tr>
            </form>
        </table>
    </div>
    ";
    } 

}else{
    echo "Hubo un error en la consulta";
}
?>
    </body>
    </html>

actualiza.php
<head>
<title>Actualizacion completada.</title>
<META name='robot' content='noindex, nofollow'>
```

```
<?php
```

// Actualizamos en funcion del id que recibimos

```
$id = $_POST['id'];

//$id_Funcionario = $_POST['id_Funcionario'];
$primer_Nombre = $_POST['primer_Nombre'];
$segundo_Nombre = $_POST['segundo_Nombre'];
$primer_Apellido = $_POST['primer_Apellido'];
$segundo_Apellido = $_POST['segundo_Apellido'];
$cargo_Funcionario = $_POST['cargo_Funcionario'];
$telefono_Funcionario = $_POST['telefono_Funcionario'];
$edad_Funcionario = $_POST['edad_Funcionario'];
$sexo_Funcionario = $_POST['sexo_Funcionario'];
$fecha = date("d-m-Y");

$conexion =  mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","admin123","database");


$sSQL="UPDATE usuario SET 
                            primer_Nombre=?, 
                            segundo_Nombre=?, 
                            primer_Apellido=?, 
                            segundo_Apellido=?, 
                            cargo_Funcionario=?, 
                            telefono_Funcionario=?, 
                            edad_Funcionario=?, 
                            sexo_Funcionario=?

        WHERE id_Funcionario=?";  //aquí habría que filtrar por algún valor

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conexion, $sSQL)) {

    /*Agrega variables a una sentencia preparada como parametros*/
    /* ligar parámetros para marcadores */
    /*IMPORTANTE: Si id no es numérico en la base de datos, cambia la i por una s*/
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssssiisi", $id_Funcionario,$primer_Nombre,$segundo_Nombre,$primer_Apellido,$segundo_Apellido,$cargo_Funcionario,$telefono_Funcionario,$edad_Funcionario,$sexo_Funcionario);

    /* Ejecuta una consulta preparada */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    if (mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)){
        echo mysqli_stmt_errno($stmt);      
    }else{
        echo "Se actualizaron: ".mysqli_affected_rows($conexion)." Prueba temporal: ".mysqli_error($conexion);    
    }
    mysqli_stmt_close ($stmt);
}else{

    echo "Hubo un error en la actual";
    echo '<a href="javascript:history.go(-1);">Atras</a';
}       
?>
```

Comment: Cristian yo me refería a [actualizar la otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/146633/29967), poniendo el nuevo código al final de la misma, no a que crearas una nueva.

Comment: era que pudiera ver todo el codigo

Comment: cual es el error? no lo veo , pono aca en los comentarios o modifica la pregunta. si no, no te podremos ayudar.

Comment: como hago para actualizar los registros de mi base de datos no me actualizan y no se que error tengo?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que aquí muestras otras cosas que en la otra consulta no mostrabas. Aquí aparece ahora una consulta `UPDATE`. Y la consulta tiene el mismo problema que se había corregido en la anterior, o sea, esa consulta también es vulnerable. Es importante que trates de entender el concepto básico de las consultas preparadas. En el `UPDATE` también tienes que hacer `bind`  de las variables aparte. También usas la extensión `mysql_*`... como ocurría en la otra pregunta.

Comment: pero si necesito hacer primero la consulta?

Comment: No sé a qué te refieres al decir *si necesitas hacer primero la consulta*. Yo veo que tú tienes dos tipos de consulta, una `SELECT` y otra `UPDATE`. Pero no explicas nada más. Por ejemplo, ¿el `UPDATE` es en base a algún criterio?, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este código es para el archivo `modificarProceso.php`.

El otro código ya tienes una respuesta en la otra pregunta donde se ha explicado con más detalle cómo funcionan las consultas preparadas.

> **NOTA MUY IMPORTANTE: Tienes que especificar en base a qué criterio se
>   hará el `UPDATE` usando un `WHERE`, de lo contrario, se actualizarán
>   todos los datos de la tabla con esos valores.**

Es decir, a tu consulta le faltaría algún filtro:

```
    $sSQL="UPDATE usuario SET 
                                id_Funcionario=?, 
                                primer_Nombre=?, 
                                segundo_Nombre=?, 
                                primer_Apellido=?, 
                                segundo_Apellido=?, 
                                cargo_Funcionario=?, 
                                telefono_Funcionario=?, 
                                edad_Funcionario=?, 
                                sexo_Funcionario=?
            WHERE id=1";  //aquí habría que filtrar por algún valor
```

actualiza.php

```
<head>
    <title>Actualizacion completada.</title>
    <META name='robot' content='noindex, nofollow'>
</head>

<body>

    <?php
// Actualizamos en funcion del id que recibimos

    $id = $_POST['id'];

    $primer_Nombre = $_POST['primer_Nombre'];
    $segundo_Nombre = $_POST['segundo_Nombre'];
    $primer_Apellido = $_POST['primer_Apellido'];
    $segundo_Apellido = $_POST['segundo_Apellido'];
    $cargo_Funcionario = $_POST['cargo_Funcionario'];
    $telefono_Funcionario = $_POST['telefono_Funcionario'];
    $edad_Funcionario = $_POST['edad_Funcionario'];
    $sexo_Funcionario = $_POST['sexo_Funcionario'];
    $fecha = date("d-m-Y");

    $conexion =  mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","admin123","database");


    $sSQL="UPDATE usuario SET 
                                primer_Nombre=?, 
                                segundo_Nombre=?, 
                                primer_Apellido=?, 
                                segundo_Apellido=?, 
                                cargo_Funcionario=?, 
                                telefono_Funcionario=?, 
                                edad_Funcionario=?, 
                                sexo_Funcionario=?

            WHERE id_Funcionario=?";

    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conexion, $sSQL)) {

        /*Agrega variables a una sentencia preparada como parametros*/
        /* ligar parámetros para marcadores */
        /*IMPORTANTE: Si id no es numérico en la base de datos, cambia la i por una s*/
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssssiisi", $primer_Nombre,$segundo_Nombre,$primer_Apellido,$segundo_Apellido,$cargo_Funcionario,$telefono_Funcionario,$edad_Funcionario,$sexo_Funcionario,$id);

        /* Ejecuta una consulta preparada */
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

        if (mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)){
            echo mysqli_stmt_errno($stmt);      
        }else{
            echo "Se actualizaron: ".mysqli_affected_rows($conexion);       
        }
        mysqli_stmt_close ($stmt);
    }else{

        echo "Hubo un error preparando la consulta";
    }
```

Comment: Comentarios movidos al [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74841/discussion-on-answer-by-a-cedano-realizar-update-de-los-registros-en-php)

Comment: Cedano me puedes ayudar en algo más

Comment: cedano me puedes ayudar en algo más

Comment: @CristianAntonioTrujilloGris si está a mi alcance te ayudaré, yo o cualquier otro usuario. En todo caso, se requiere que plantees tu duda o problema en una pregunta.

Comment: en que tiempos se conecta para ver si me puedes ayudar

Comment: Señor cedano necesito ayuda urgente con algo de php y mysql

Comment: @CristianAntonioTrujilloGris ¿planteaste una pregunta con el problema?

Comment: si claro ya la plantie

Comment: @CristianAntonioTrujilloGris ¿y cuál es la pregunta, puedes indicarme el enlace?

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/166265/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-generar-mi-reporte-de-excel-por-mes