# como actualizo los registros de una base de datos?

Tags: php

Tengo este código, pero me muestra este error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: id_Funcionario in C:\xampp\htdocs\Aeroasistencia\aplicacionTruji\actualiza.php on line 26
```

Estoy haciendo la consulta mediante el `id` de cada persona para que me muestre los datos y poder actualizar el que se requiera de cada persona.

Estoy utilizando MySQL .

Este es el formulario, cuyo archivo es `modificarFuncionario.php`:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Iniciar actualización.</title>
    <META name='robot' content='noindex, nofollow'>
</head>

<body>

    <div align="center">
        <table border="0" width="600" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt" id="table1">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><h3 align="center">Actualizacion de datos</h3></td>
            </tr>
            <form method="POST" action="modificarProceso.php">
                <tr>
                    <td width="50%">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td width="50%">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="50%">
                        <p align="center"><b>ID del funcionario a actualizar: </b></td>
                            <td width="50%">
                                <p align="center"><input type="text" name="id" size="20"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="50%">&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td width="50%">&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="100%" colspan="2">
                                        <p align="center">
                                            <input type="submit" value="Iniciar actualización" name="btn-actulizar"></td>
                                            <input type="button" value="Volver de donde viniste!" onclick="history.back(-1)" />
                                        </tr>
                                    </form>
                                </table>
                            </div>

                        </body>

                        </html>
```

Aqui estoy haciendo la consulta, archivo `modificarProceso.php`:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Datos a actualizar.</title>
    <META name='robot' content='noindex, nofollow'>
</head>

<?php 
echo "<body>";
$id = $_POST['id'];

$conexion =  mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","admin123","database");

$query = "  SELECT
                    id_Funcionario,
                    primer_Nombre,
                    segundo_Nombre,
                    primer_Apellido,
                    segundo_Apellido,
                    cargo_Funcionario,
                    telefono_Funcionario,
                    edad_Funcionario,
                    sexo_Funcionario
            FROM usuario
            WHERE id_Funcionario = '".$id."'";

/*Prepara la setencia SQl para su ejecucion*/
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conexion, $query)) {

    /*Agrega variables a una sentencia preparada como parametros*/
    /* ligar parámetros para marcadores */
    /*IMPORTANTE: Si id no es numérico en la base de datos, cambia la i por una s*/
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $id);

    /* Ejecuta una consulta preparada */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /*Se transfiere los  resultados de la ultima consulta*/
    $stmt->store_result();

    /* Vincula las variables a una setencia preparada para el almacenamineto de result */
    $stmt->bind_result($id_Funcionario, $primer_Nombre, $segundo_Nombre, $primer_Apellido, $segundo_Apellido, $cargo_Funcionario, $telefono_Funcionario, $edad_Funcionario, $sexo_Funcionario);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo "

    <div align='center'>
        <table border='0' width='600' style='font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt' id='table1'>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='2'><h3 align='center'>Actualice los datos que considere</h3></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='2'>En los campos del formulario puede ver los valores actuales,
                si no se cambian los valores se mantienen iguales.</td>
            </tr>
            <form method='POST' action='actualiza.php'>
            <tr>
                <td width='50%'>&nbsp;</td>
                <td width='50%'>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><b>Cedula: </b></td>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><input type='text' name='id_funcinario' size='20' value='".$id_Funcionario."'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><b>Primer Nombre :</b></td>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><input type='text' name='primer_Nombre' size='20' value='".$primer_Nombre."'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><b>Segundo Nombre :</b></td>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><input type='text' name='segundo_Nombre' size='20' value='".$segundo_Nombre."'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><b>Primer Apellido :</b></td>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><input type='text' name='primer_Apellido' size='20' value='".$primer_Apellido."'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><b>Segundo Apellido :</b></td>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><input type='text' name='segundo_Apellido' size='20' value='".$segundo_Apellido."'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><b>Cargo Funcionario :</b></td>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><input type='text' name='cargo_Funcionario' size='20' value='".$cargo_Funcionario."'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><b>Telefono Funcionario :</b></td>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><input type='text' name='telefono_Funcionario' size='20' value='".$telefono_Funcionario."'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><b>Edad Funcionario :</b></td>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><input type='text' name='edad_Funcionario' size='20' value='".$edad_Funcionario."'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><b>Sexo Funcionario :</b></td>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><input type='text' name='sexo_Funcionario' size='20' value='".$sexo_Funcionario."'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width='50%'>&nbsp;</td>
                <td width='50%'>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <input type='hidden' name='id' value='$id'>
            <tr>
                <td width='100%' colspan='2'>
                <p align='center'>
                <input type='submit' value='Actualizar datos' name='B1'></td>
            </tr>
            </form>
        </table>
    </div>
    ";
    } 

}else{
    echo "Hubo un error en la consulta";
}
?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Aquí estoy haciendo la actualización de datos, archivo `Actualiza.php`:

```
<head>
    <title>Actualizacion completada.</title>
    <META name='robot' content='noindex, nofollow'>
</head>

<body>

    <?php
// Actualizamos en funcion del id que recibimos

    $id = $_POST['id'];

    $primer_Nombre = $_POST['primer_Nombre'];
    $segundo_Nombre = $_POST['segundo_Nombre'];
    $primer_Apellido = $_POST['primer_Apellido'];
    $segundo_Apellido = $_POST['segundo_Apellido'];
    $cargo_Funcionario = $_POST['cargo_Funcionario'];
    $telefono_Funcionario = $_POST['telefono_Funcionario'];
    $edad_Funcionario = $_POST['edad_Funcionario'];
    $sexo_Funcionario = $_POST['sexo_Funcionario'];
    $fecha = date("d-m-Y");

    $conexion =  mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","admin123","database");


    $sSQL="UPDATE usuario SET ( id_Funcionario  ='".$id_Funcionario."', 
                                primer_Nombre ='".$primer_Nombre."', 
                                segundo_Nombre ='".$segundo_Nombre."', 
                                primer_Apellido ='".$primer_Apellido."', 
                                segundo_Apellido ='".$segundo_Apellido."', 
                                cargo_Funcionario ='".$cargo_Funcionario."', 
                                telefono_Funcionario ='".$telefono_Funcionario."', 
                                edad_Funcionario ='".$edad_Funcionario."', 
                                sexo_Funcionario ='".$sexo_Funcionario."')";

    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conexion, $sSQL)) {

        /*Agrega variables a una sentencia preparada como parametros*/
        /* ligar parámetros para marcadores */
        /*IMPORTANTE: Si id no es numérico en la base de datos, cambia la i por una s*/
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "isssssiis", $id_Funcionario,$primer_Nombre,$segundo_Nombre,$primer_Apellido,$segundo_Apellido,$cargo_Funcionario,$telefono_Funcionario,$edad_Funcionario,$sexo_Funcionario);

        /* Ejecuta una consulta preparada */
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

        if (mysqli_stmt_error($stmt)){
            echo mysqli_stmt_errno($stmt);      
        }else{
            echo "Se actualizaron: ".mysqli_affected_rows($conexion);       
        }
        mysqli_stmt_close ($stmt);
    }else{

        echo "Hubo un error preparando la consulta";
    }       
    ?>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Cristian, hace falta controlar las variables. `Undefined variable` indica que intentas usar una variable que no existe. Por otra parte, tu código no funcionará, ya que estás mezclando consultas preparadas con consultas a las que les pasas los datos directamente. [En esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/146831/29967) traté de ayudarte a corregir ese problema... debes escribir las consultas así, usando `?` en vez de los datos directamente, los cuales deben pasarse con `bind_param`. En aquella respuesta se me escapó un error que había en tu `UPDATE`, los paréntesis que usas.

Answer (score 1):

el problema esta en el archivo `Actualiza.php`

tu defines

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

pero no la utilizas, cambia a

```
$id_Funcionario =  $_POST['id'];
```

espero que te ayude

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda pero no es ese el error

Answer (score 0):

Bueno primero no has definido la variable $id_Funcionario ese es un error todas estan menos esa definela con el valor del post ,no se si eso sea el error pero es uno.

```html
 $id = $_POST['id'];
    $primer_Nombre = $_POST['primer_Nombre'];
    $segundo_Nombre = $_POST['segundo_Nombre'];
    $primer_Apellido = $_POST['primer_Apellido'];
    $segundo_Apellido = $_POST['segundo_Apellido'];
    $cargo_Funcionario = $_POST['cargo_Funcionario'];
    $telefono_Funcionario = $_POST['telefono_Funcionario'];
    $edad_Funcionario = $_POST['edad_Funcionario'];
    $sexo_Funcionario = $_POST['sexo_Funcionario'];
    $fecha = date("d-m-Y");

esta no esta definida

**id_Funcionario  ='".$id_Funcionario."',**
```

en el archivo actualiza.php

Deberia probar esto

```html
  $id = $_POST['id'];
        $id_Funcionario = $_POST['id_Funcionario'];
        $primer_Nombre = $_POST['primer_Nombre'];
        $segundo_Nombre = $_POST['segundo_Nombre'];
        $primer_Apellido = $_POST['primer_Apellido'];
        $segundo_Apellido = $_POST['segundo_Apellido'];
        $cargo_Funcionario = $_POST['cargo_Funcionario'];
        $telefono_Funcionario = $_POST['telefono_Funcionario'];
        $edad_Funcionario = $_POST['edad_Funcionario'];
        $sexo_Funcionario = $_POST['sexo_Funcionario'];
        $fecha = date("d-m-Y");
```

Comment: eso ya lo hize pero sigue igual

Answer (score 0):

Bueno el name esta como **id_funcinario** y debe ser **id_Funcionario**

```html
    <tr>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><b>Cedula: </b></td>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><input type='text' name='id_funcinario' size='20' value='".**$id_Funcionario**."'></td>
            </tr>
```

La variable con el cambio

```html
 <td width='50%'><p align='center'><b>Cedula: </b></td>
                <td width='50%'><p align='center'><input type='text' name='id_Funcionario' size='20' value='".$id_Funcionario."'></td>
```