# ¿Cómo puedo generar mi reporte de excel por mes?

Tags: php, mysql, excel

Éste es mi script en donde genero mi reporte en excel el cual funciona perfectamente.

Lo que busco es que pueda realizar las descargas indicando el mes para evitar descargar todos los meses en un solo archivo.

### index.php

```
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

    <title>generando RIPS...</title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="Swnk" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0" />

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png" />
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <header>
            <h1>Registros Individuales de Prestación de Servicios de Salud</h1>
        </header>

        <form action="reporteexcel.php">
            <label>Mes: </label>
            <select name="mes">
                <option value="Enero">Enero</option>
                <option value="Febrero">Febrero</option>
                <option value="Marzo">Marzo</option>
                <option value="Abril">Abril</option>
                <option value="Mayo">Mayo</option>
                <option value="Junio">Junio</option>
                <option value="Julio">Julio</option>
                <option value="Agosto">Agosto</option>
                <option value="Septiembre">Septiembre</option>
                <option value="Octubre">Octubre</option>
                <option value="Noviembre">Noviembre</option>
                <option value="Diciembre">Diciembre</option>

            </select>

            <label>Año: </label>
            <select name="año">
                <option value="2018">2018</option>
                <option value="2019">2019</option>
                <option value="2020">2020</option>
                <option value="2021">2021</option>
                <option value="2022">2022</option>
                <option value="2023">2023</option>
                <option value="2023">2024</option>
                <option value="2024">2018</option>
                <option value="2025">2025</option>
                <option value="2026">2026</option>
                <option value="2027">2027</option>
                <option value="2028">2028</option>
                <option value="2029">2029</option>
                <option value="2030">2030</option>

            </select>
            <br>

            <br><input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Generar" onclick="location='http://localhost/Aeroasistencia/Reportes/reporteexcel.php'">
        </form>

        <footer>
            <p>
                &copy; Copyright  by trujii :D
            </p>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
```

### `reporteexcel.php`

```
<?php
    $conexion = new mysqli('localhost','root','admin123','database',3306);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("La conexión con el servidor de base de datos falló: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    $consulta = "SELECT servicio_No, hora, tipo_Ambulancia, tipo_Traslado, horario, cliente, fecha_Solicitud, hora1, hor, regulador FROM servicio ORDER BY servicio_No";
    $resultado = $conexion->query($consulta);
    if($resultado->num_rows > 0 ){

        date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota');

        if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli')
            die('Este archivo solo se puede ver desde un navegador web');

        /** Se agrega la libreria PHPExcel */
        require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';

        // Se crea el objeto PHPExcel
        $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

        // Se asignan las propiedades del libro
        $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Trujii") //Autor
                             ->setLastModifiedBy(";D") //Ultimo usuario que lo modificó
                             ->setTitle("Reporte Excel con PHP y MySQL")
                             ->setSubject("Reporte Excel con PHP y MySQL")
                             ->setDescription("Reporte de servicios")
                             ->setKeywords("reporte servicio")
                             ->setCategory("Reporte excel");

        $tituloReporte = "Relación de servicios";
        $titulosColumnas = array('SERVICIO NO', 'HORA', 'TIPO AMBULANCIA', 'TIPO TRASLADO', 'HORARIO', 'CLIENTE', 'FECHA SOLICITUD', 'HORA', 'HOR', 'REGULADOR');

        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                    ->mergeCells('A1:J1');

        // Se agregan los titulos del reporte
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                    ->setCellValue('A1',$tituloReporte)
                    ->setCellValue('A3',  $titulosColumnas[0])
                    ->setCellValue('B3',  $titulosColumnas[1])
                    ->setCellValue('C3',  $titulosColumnas[2])
                    ->setCellValue('D3',  $titulosColumnas[3])
                    ->setCellValue('E3',  $titulosColumnas[4])
                    ->setCellValue('F3',  $titulosColumnas[5])
                    ->setCellValue('G3',  $titulosColumnas[6])
                    ->setCellValue('H3',  $titulosColumnas[7])
                    ->setCellValue('I3',  $titulosColumnas[8])
                    ->setCellValue('J3',  $titulosColumnas[9])
                    ->setCellValue('K3',  $titulosColumnas[10]));

        //Se agregan los datos de los alumnos
        $i = 4;
        while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_array()) {
            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                    ->setCellValue('A'.$i,  $fila['servicio_No'])
                    ->setCellValue('B'.$i,  $fila['hora'])
                    ->setCellValue('C'.$i,  $fila['tipo_Ambulancia'])
                    ->setCellValue('D'.$i,  $fila['tipo_Traslado'])
                    ->setCellValue('E'.$i,  $fila['horario'])
                    ->setCellValue('F'.$i,  $fila['cliente'])
                    ->setCellValue('G'.$i,  $fila['fecha_Solicitud'])
                    ->setCellValue('H'.$i,  $fila['hora1'])
                    ->setCellValue('I'.$i,  $fila['hor'])
                    ->setCellValue('J'.$i,  $fila['regulador']));
                    $i++;
        }

        $estiloTituloReporte = array(
            'font' => array(
                'name'      => 'Verdana',
                'bold'      => true,
                'italic'    => false,
                'strike'    => false,
                'size' =>20,
                    'color'     => array(
                        'rgb' => 'FFFFFF'
                    )
            ),
            'fill' => array(
                'type'  => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                'color' => array('argb' => 'FF220835')
            ),
            'borders' => array(
                'allborders' => array(
                    'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_NONE                    
                )
            ), 
            'alignment' =>  array(
                    'horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,
                    'vertical'   => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER,
                    'rotation'   => 0,
                    'wrap'          => TRUE
            )
        );

        $estiloTituloColumnas = array(
            'font' => array(
                'name'      => 'Arial',
                'bold'      => true,                          
                'color'     => array(
                    'rgb' => 'FFFFFF'
                )
            ),
            'fill'  => array(
                'type'      => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_GRADIENT_LINEAR,
                'rotation'   => 90,
                'startcolor' => array(
                    'rgb' => '00abdd'
                ),
                'endcolor'   => array(
                    'argb' => '00abdd'
                )
            ),
            'borders' => array(
                'top'     => array(
                    'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_MEDIUM ,
                    'color' => array(
                        'rgb' => '143860'
                    )
                ),
                'bottom'     => array(
                    'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_MEDIUM ,
                    'color' => array(
                        'rgb' => '143860'
                    )
                )
            ),
            'alignment' =>  array(
                    'horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,
                    'vertical'   => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER,
                    'wrap'          => TRUE
            ));

        $estiloInformacion = new PHPExcel_Style();
        $estiloInformacion->applyFromArray(
            array(
                'font' => array(
                'name'      => 'Arial',               
                'color'     => array(
                    'rgb' => '000000'
                )
            ),
            'fill'  => array(
                'type'      => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
                'color'     => array('argb' => '00abdd')
            ),
            'borders' => array(
                'left'     => array(
                    'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN ,
                    'color' => array(
                        'rgb' => '3a2a47'
                    )
                )             
            )
        ));

        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:J1')->applyFromArray($estiloTituloReporte);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A3:J3')->applyFromArray($estiloTituloColumnas);      
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setSharedStyle($estiloInformacion, "A4:BD".($i-1));

        for($i = 'A'; $i <= 'J'; $i++){
            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)            
                ->getColumnDimension($i)->setAutoSize(TRUE);
        }

        // Se asigna el nombre a la hoja
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('servicio');

        // Se activa la hoja para que sea la que se muestre cuando el archivo se abre
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
        // Inmovilizar paneles 
        //$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->freezePane('A4');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->freezePaneByColumnAndRow(0,10);

        // Se manda el archivo al navegador web, con el nombre que se indica (Excel2007)
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="ReportedeSERVICIOS.xlsx"');
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
        $objWriter->save('php://output');
        exit;

    }
    else{
        print_r('No hay resultados para mostrar');
    }
?>
```

Comment: no veo la consulta que haces para pedir por mes

Comment: es que no tengo idea de como hacerla

Comment: ¿Cómo se llama la columna de la tabla que almacena la fecha por la que quieres filtrar? ¿Esa columna es del tipo `DATETIME`? ¿El filtro sería sólo por mes o también por año?

Comment: pues mira yo tengo en la tabla servicio una columna llamada fecha_Solicitud la idea es poder descargar el archivo de los servicios realizados por mes y año

Comment: ¿Pero todos los servicios ordenados por mes y año o sólo los registros filtrados de un mes/año específicos?

Comment: registro filtrados de un mes/año especificos

Comment: @A.cedano el codigo que publique funciona realiza la descarga correctamente el problema es que me descarga todos los servicios de todos los meses, lo que busco es poder realizar la descarga del mes que el usuario le indique.

Comment: En ese caso tendrías que ponerle un filtro a la consulta. Por ejemplo, si quieres los registros de abril del 2018: `$consulta = "SELECT servicio_No, hora, tipo_Ambulancia, tipo_Traslado, horario, cliente, fecha_Solicitud, hora1, hor, regulador FROM servicio WHERE YEAR(fecha_Solicitud)=2018 AND MONTH(fecha_Solicitud)=4 ORDER BY servicio_No";`. En cuanto al código PHP, le puedes pasar los valores del filtro en parámetro a una función para hacerlo dinámico, o sea, que cuando quieras los registros de enero de 2016 le pases los valores `2016,1` a esa función.

Comment: no entiendo? como

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no entiendes? Prueba el código de forma manual primero, probando con un año y mes puesto a mano y di si funciona y si es lo que quieres. Luego si quieres te escribo una respuesta indicando una función. No sé si la consulta que quieres es como la indicada en mi anterior comentario.

Comment: ok @A.cedadno lo voy a realizar y te estoy contando como me fue

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77801/discussion-between-cristian-antonio-trujillo-gris-and-a-cedano).

Comment: voy añadir mi codigo HTML

Comment: @A.cedano si viste mi formulario?

Comment: @A.cedano si puedes ayudarme

Comment: @A.Cedano si puedes ayudar?

Comment: Cristian ¿cuál es el estado actual de tu problema en este asunto?

Comment: @A.Cedano el estado actual es que necesito descargar el archivo por mes porque en este momento me descarga todo el archivo con los registros de todos los meses